# I want to create a program that automatically updates the maximum value when I press the button

Tags: c#

[image]

I'm sorry to ask you a basic question first. It hasn't been long since I learned C#.

```
 private void numberButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();

        int randNumber = rand.Next(1, 1000);

        randomNumber.Text = randNumber.ToString();

        bestScoreLabel.Text = randomNumber.Text;
    }
```

How can I implement the function so that the maximum value of the bestScoreLabel is automatically updated when I click the number button as shown in the picture above?

**Currently, the code is configured as above, but the problem occurs that the maximum and current values are the same output.**

Comment: Remember the best score in a field of the form class and compare each score with the best score to decide whether you need to update the best score.

Comment: The concept of storing the highest score is not understood. Do I need to make a array?

Comment: int max = int.MinValue; 

       
        int[] numbers = { };
 
        
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            if (numbers[i] > max)
            {
                max = numbers[i]; 
        }  // What numbers should be in the array?

Comment: You don't need an array, just compare each number as they're created

Comment: *"The concept of storing the highest score is not understood"*. Really? You don't understand the concept of assigning a number to a variable?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The idea is to have a variable to keep tracking the max number.

```
 private static int _maxNumber = 0;

 private void numberButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
   Random rand = new Random();
   int randNumber = rand.Next(1, 1000);
   randomNumber.Text = randNumber.ToString(); 

   if (_maxNumber < randNumber)
   {
      _maxNumber = randNUmber;
   }
   bestScoreLabel.Text = _maxNumber.ToString();
  }
```

Comment: `_maxNumber` doesn't have to be `static`, while the Random object should be declared as a `static` field (of course outside the event handler)